# in Flutter, make a list of api call inside one api call

Tags: flutter, api

In one of my flutter app, at first I want to call an api, which will return a list of item, and the item will be shown in a ListView. I also need to call another api for each item of the ListView to fetch description of that item and show the description to each item according to their id. How can I resolve this scenario. In RxJava, there is an operator called flatmap which did the same things without any hassle. But in flutter, How can I implement this. Here is my 2 function

```
class HomeRepositoryImpl extends HomeRepository {

  HomeGraphQLService homeGraphQLService;
  HomeMapper homeMapper;

  HomeRepositoryImpl(HomeGraphQLService homeGraphQLService, HomeMapper homeMapper) {
    this.homeGraphQLService = homeGraphQLService;
    this.homeMapper = homeMapper;
  }

  @override
  Future<List<Course>> getAllCourseOf(String className, String groupName) async {
    final response = await homeGraphQLService.getAllCourseOf(className, groupName);
    return homeMapper.toCourses(response).where((course) => course.isAvailable);
  }

  @override
  Future<CourseProgressAndPerformance> getProgressAndPerformanceAnalysisOf(String subjectCode) async {
    final response = await homeGraphQLService.getProgressAndPerformanceAnalysisOf(subjectCode);
    return homeMapper.toProgressAndPerformance(response);
  }

}
```

In the above class, first I call getAllCourseOf() function to get a list of course and show them in list view. I need to call getProgressAndPerformanceAnalysisOf(courseId) to fetch description of each item and show the description in each item of that list.

So what is recommended way to do so.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure on how the listing would be presented, my guess is you're looking for `Stream` and `asyncMap()`

Here's an example implementation that would give you a list of `CourseProgressAndPerformance`, this is the direction I'd investigate.

```dart
var perfList = Stream
 .fromIterable(listOfCourses)
 .asyncMap((course) => getProgressAndPerformanceAnalysisOf(courseId))
 .toList();
```